# How to drop relation variables in Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I worked using interactive mode of Pig. During this I have loaded different data into different different relatin variables such as :

```
grunt> student_data = LOAD '/home/training/Desktop/studentResult.txt' as(name:chararray,dept:chararray,marks:bytearray);

grunt> emp_data = LOAD '/home/training/Desktop/studentResult.txt' as(name:chararray,dept:chararray,marks:bytearray);
```

Now I want to delete or drop these variables for re-use. How can I do it?

Comment: Just use it as it is and old data will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

In both Grunt shell and batch mode, we can not delete the relation variables in Pig. But, we can assign the new relation to the same variable, the old relation/bag will be overwritten.

To clear the commands entered in Shell, type 'clear' in shell, this avoids the ambiguity with the variables.

Comment: Thanks Lakshman, now I have clear idea that we can't delete relation variables. This is what I wanted.

Thanks once again brother